# Creating a moderatly complex plotting class in c++ for QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I need to write a class which allows plotting of x vs y data (scatter plots, line plots), and the Application is done using QtQuick. It should be possible that several curves are shown, and maybe added dynamically depending on user selection. Also, two y-axis for different quantities which share the x-axis should be possible. Right now I implemented the plotting of a single curve as a QQuickItem using QSGGeometryNode. I think the final plot class should contain a vector of these curves and the axes and ticks including labels as object. I guess I will do the axes and ticks using a QQuickPaintedItem.

However, I am a bit lost (being new to Qt and QML) with how to organize this. If it were widgets, I would just create child widgets for the axis and plot curves. Is something similar possible in QtQuick?

Comment: Have you looked at the qml charts module https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-qmlmodule.html

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I cannot use it as we try to use the LGPL license.

Comment: Those are available under mit http://jwintz.me/blog/2014/02/15/qchart-dot-js-qml-binding-for-chart-dot-js/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually I was not aware, that I can create child QQuickItems like in the widget case. That means If I have a PlotCurve object which is a QQuickItem I make a PlotWindow object like this

```
#ifndef PLOTWINDOW_H
#define PLOTWINDOW_H

#include <QQuickItem>
#include "plotcurve.h"

class PlotWindow : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PlotWindow();

private:
    QVector<PlotCurve *> _curves;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // PLOTWINDOW_H
```

and add it in the constructor (as an example)

```
PlotWindow::PlotWindow()
{
    _curves.append(new PlotCurve(this));
    _curves[0]->setVisible(true);
    _curves[0]->setWidth(300);
    _curves[0]->setHeight(300);
}
```

The axis I can do as QQuickPaintedItem and add them in a similar fashion to the PlotWindow object.

Comment: You can check out QCustomPlot it's written for QWidget but it's not difficult to port it to QtQuick. I have done it myself.